# Make JavaScript link open in new window with document.write

Tags: javascript

I'm to figure out how to code so that the link opens into a new window? Is this the correct way to do that?

```
<script>
  var copyright = "&copy; ";
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getFullYear();
  var db = " Doing Business";
  var str = new String(" Link");
  document.write(copyright + n + str.link("https://www.google.com"));
  document.write(db); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please stop using [String.link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link).  It's old, deprecated, and smelly.  It also doesn't support what you are trying to do.

You can construct a link with the appropriate `target` attribute ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)) to open in a new tab as follows:

```
var myLink = "<a target='_blank' href='https://www.google.com'>Link</a>";
document.write(copyright + n + " " + myLink);
```

Comment: I thought I smelled something, and know my code has some funk about it...but your code smells wonderful! Thank you, it works exactly as I need it too.